# Not able to access svn repo located in a remote server from different remote server with subversion

Tags: authentication, svn, svnsync

I am trying to create subversion repository mirror in a remote server using "svnsync" through command line and the actual repo is located in different remote server.I am able to access this repo from SVNSLIK, but not able to connect subversion of windows compatible

*command:*

```
svnsync init file:///repository http://repoURL/trunk/repoName --source-username AAA --source-password PWD
```

*Authentication realm:* XXX

*Username:* AAA Password: PWD

Again asked username and password, even i entered correct authentication info, thrown error.

```
Error: svnsync:E215004:Unable to connect to a repository at URL http://repoURL/trunk/repoName
```

Plz help me on this.

Comment: When I googled for your error code E215004, it seems to indicate a authentication error: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too manytimes (is there any more error output after the line you posted?)
Have you tried accessing the url via a browser and see what happens, since it is a http url?

Comment: Also I am assuming that the htp:// protocol only is a typo in your question as it should be http://.

Comment: no typo error,i am not able to post this question if i use http, so i mentioned htp in the question.

Comment: i am able to access the repo(URL) from browser, but not able to acces through command line in windows usning svnsync. i installed win32svn(Subversion Windows Installer).

Comment: Do you have to log in when you use the url via the browser?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for commenting on this.                               For accessing repo from browser,i need to enter credentilas. I installed WIN32SVN on windows server

Answer (score 0):

I escaped from the problem. In source server(where source code repository exists), subversion client with version - win32svn1.6 was installed. But in destination server, I installed win32svn1.8. May be this is causing the problem. So, I uninstalled win32svn1.8 (from destination server), then installed subversion client with version win32svn1.7. Now it working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old thread (asked 3years ago as of this posting) but I can provide a different perspective for other users in same scenario.

My source repo was 1.6 and destination was the current svn 1.9.4 on CentOS 6.8. I got the same error

`E215004: No more credentials or we tried too manytimes`

I have another repo syncing (svn1.6 -> svn1.9) and it was working fine so I compared the config. The other working repo has

`SVNPath /var/www/svn_repos/XXX`

While this new one has

`SVNParentPath /var/www/svn`

Per http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.mod_dav_svn.conf.html, those 2 cannot go at the same time. If I change one for the other, I risk breaking the automation apps using this new repo. I don't know the intimate difference between those two (SVNParentPath vs SVNPath) but I tried creating a different config in my /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf

`<Location /appX-sync>
  DAV svn
  SVNPath /var/www/svn/appX
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      # Require SSL connection for password protection.
      SSLRequireSSL
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        allow from localhost
        allow from 1.2.3.40
        allow from 1.2.3.50
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>`

And when I re-run the svnsync, it worked!